# How to make unresize-able menu in minecraft GuiMainMenu?

Tags: java, menu, minecraft

first i dont know how the title should be but i will show it below.
Im just making a custom minecraft client for my server. i just add some buttons to the main menu like Home Page, Shop, Facebook link, direct server join and when i resize the game window they change their location? idk.

[How it should be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yQ8eb.png)

[Default game window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/exqAh.png)

[When i resize it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hdG2P.png)

GuiMainMenu.java:

```
/** See all: https://pastebin.com/PagvD7hh */ 
public void initGui()
{
    this.viewportTexture = new DynamicTexture(256, 256);
    this.backgroundTexture = this.mc.getTextureManager().getDynamicTextureLocation("background", this.viewportTexture);
    this.field_193978_M = this.fontRendererObj.getStringWidth("© Mojang AB");
    this.field_193979_N = this.width - this.field_193978_M - 2;
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTime(new Date());

    if (calendar.get(2) + 1 == 12 && calendar.get(5) == 24)
    {
        this.splashText = "Merry X-mas!";
    }
    else if (calendar.get(2) + 1 == 1 && calendar.get(5) == 1)
    {
        this.splashText = "Happy new year!";
    }
    else if (calendar.get(2) + 1 == 10 && calendar.get(5) == 31)
    {
        this.splashText = "OOoooOOOoooo! Spooky!";
    }

    int i = 24;
    int j = this.height / 4 + 48;

    if (this.mc.isDemo())
    {
        this.addDemoButtons(j, 24);
    }
    else
    {
        this.addSingleplayerMultiplayerButtons(j, 24);
    }

    this.buttonList.add(new GuiButton(0, this.width / 2 - 100, j + 90 + 30, 98, 20, I18n.format("menu.options")));
    this.buttonList.add(new GuiButton(4, this.width / 2 + 2, j + 90 + 30, 98, 20, I18n.format("menu.quit")));
    this.buttonList.add(new GuiButtonLanguage(5, this.width / 2 - 124, j + 90 + 30));

    synchronized (this.threadLock)
    {
        this.openGLWarning1Width = this.fontRendererObj.getStringWidth(this.openGLWarning1);
        this.openGLWarning2Width = this.fontRendererObj.getStringWidth(this.openGLWarning2);
        int k = Math.max(this.openGLWarning1Width, this.openGLWarning2Width);
        this.openGLWarningX1 = (this.width - k) / 2;
        this.openGLWarningY1 = (this.buttonList.get(0)).yPosition - 24;
        this.openGLWarningX2 = this.openGLWarningX1 + k;
        this.openGLWarningY2 = this.openGLWarningY1 + 24;
    }

    this.mc.setConnectedToRealms(false);

    if (Minecraft.getMinecraft().gameSettings.getOptionOrdinalValue(GameSettings.Options.REALMS_NOTIFICATIONS) && !this.hasCheckedForRealmsNotification)
    {
        RealmsBridge realmsbridge = new RealmsBridge();
        this.realmsNotification = realmsbridge.getNotificationScreen(this);
        this.hasCheckedForRealmsNotification = true;
    }

    if (this.areRealmsNotificationsEnabled())
    {
        this.realmsNotification.setGuiSize(this.width, this.height);
        this.realmsNotification.initGui();
    }

    if (Reflector.NotificationModUpdateScreen_init.exists())
    {
        this.modUpdateNotification = (GuiScreen)Reflector.call(Reflector.NotificationModUpdateScreen_init, this, this.modButton);
    }
}

/**
 * Adds Singleplayer and Multiplayer buttons on Main Menu for players who have bought the game.
 */
private void addSingleplayerMultiplayerButtons(int p_73969_1_, int p_73969_2_)
{
    this.buttonList.add(new GuiButton(1, this.width / 2 - 100, p_73969_1_, I18n.format("menu.singleplayer")));
    this.buttonList.add(new GuiButton(2, this.width / 2 - 100, p_73969_1_ + p_73969_2_, 98, 20, I18n.format("menu.multiplayer")));
    this.buttonList.add(new GuiButton(241, this.width / 2 + 2, p_73969_1_ + p_73969_2_, 98, 20, I18n.format("Hymine Server")));
    this.buttonList.add(new GuiButton(242, this.width / 2 - 154, this.height - 280, 100, 20, I18n.format("Trang Chủ")));
    this.buttonList.add(new GuiButton(243, this.width / 2 - 50, this.height - 280, 100, 20, I18n.format("Nạp Thẻ")));
    this.buttonList.add(new GuiButton(244, this.width / 2 + 4 + 50, this.height - 280, 100, 20, I18n.format("Nhóm Facebook")));

    if (Reflector.GuiModList_Constructor.exists())
    {
        this.realmsButton = this.addButton(new GuiButton(14, this.width / 2 + 2, p_73969_1_ + p_73969_2_ * 2, 98, 20, I18n.format("menu.online").replace("Minecraft", "").trim()));
        this.buttonList.add(this.modButton = new GuiButton(6, this.width / 2 - 100, p_73969_1_ + p_73969_2_ * 2, 98, 20, I18n.format("fml.menu.mods")));
    }
    else
    {
        this.realmsButton = this.addButton(new GuiButton(14, this.width / 2 - 100, p_73969_1_ + p_73969_2_ * 2, I18n.format("menu.online")));
    }
}
```

Ok so is there anyway to make it fullscreen by default and users cant resize it? or user can resize, fullscreen it but there buttons not change their location?
thanks

P/s: Sorry for my bad English. So sorry

Comment: Dont do that. Disallowing a user to be able to fullscreen an application is not a good method of solving your problem. You're just avoiding the issue, alongside making the user lose a portion of their preferenced setup. Instead, take a look at your subtraction / addition. Then see `ScaledResolution`. It'll show you why resizing can cause issues, and ways to resolve it, specifically with division.

Comment: You should fix your top-offset calculation instead.